# What mode to open a database file If i look for best speed?

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a database file, Only one user will open it for read only.

I search for best performance.

Is it good to open it in exclusive read only mode or just open it ?

Answer (score 1):

If a network is NOT involved (muti-user), then you not see really much of any difference in performance.

However, on a network? Then exclusive can make a large difference.

In fact, this is why we seen for 18+ years the OFTEN repeated performance tip to create + keep a persistent connection from the front end application to the back end file share open at ALL times.

The reason for above is that when an access front end attempts to open a table (not open the back end file), Access will attempt to gain exclusive use of the back end file. It does this, since in multi-user mode, several users can have pending updates, and thus buffers etc. require additional management, and “op locks” on the back end occur. Op-locks are part of the windows file system that allow multiple users to open and work on the file at the same time. While this setup allows multiple users to work at the  same time on the file, there is significant slowdowns due to each workstation potentially having buffers of active data that has to be written to the back end, and MORE important ensure that two users don’t update the same records at the same time. So, this flipping into multi-user mode can take significant amounts of time, and EACH TIME access tries to grab data, it will attempt to flip OUT of multi-user mode to ensure really great performance.

However, this attempt to change from multi-user mode to single user mode can take HUGE amounts of time. So, by using a persistent connection, (force to keep open) to the back end, then this LONG delay time does not occur. In addition with virus scanning software, then opening of the file can take HUGE amounts of time.

The above issue only really applies to a shared back end in a multi-user environment. And of course in such scenarios, then opening the database as exclusive would eliminate the above issues.

So Access does in fact flip between single user mode, and multi-user mode. This use of the windows file locking system will as noted MOST certainly slow down Access when it flips to multi-user mode (and worse, as noted the attempt to flip back and forth actually slows things down more than the performance gain you get had only one user open the file). Again, with one user you not notice any difference, but if 2 or more users have the back end file open, then you will see significant delays with 2 or more users. (But the persistent connection will usually remove the delays).

So, for single user mode on a single machine?

Opening normal, or exclusive likely will not change anything, and you likely not notice any performance difference. (Even read only as opposed to read/write will not be noticed.

However, the instant you introduce a network, and multiple users opening that file share from a network folder, then significant advantages can be had and seen by use of exclusive mode. As noted, the exclusive mode helps prevent the switching between single user mode on the network (for better performance), and switching to mutli-user mode (with the client workstation buffers that have write pending data). So do keep in mind that Access WILL attempt to open the back end as single user mode (this is not exclusive mode – but single user mode for better performance over the network).

However, overall, the cost of switching between the two modes tends to be the greater slowdown, then that of the speed advantages when working with a file share over a network.

So, exclusive mode when a network is involved will often result in substantial performance increases.

ON a local machine with no network? Because one has so much processing power, then opening as full read/write, or read only does not usually result in any noticeable performance gains.

So, the answer here only really applies if you are working Access files over a network. For local un-split databases on a single workstation you not gain anything of notice regardless of what mode you open the database in, or even in fact if you use a snapshot query (read only) as opposed to a query that has full read/write results.